# jQuery animate and fade background image at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

I have a selector I'm trying to animate and at the same time fade out it's background image and fade in another background image. This is what I have so far. The script works fine, but it animates first then fades. Do you know a way so it animates and fades at the same time?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selector").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({left: "75px"}, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $(this).addClass("selector-hover").fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: just call the animate on the same element, but not in the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright use this example from the jquery animate page

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function(){
  $( "#block1" ).animate( { width: "90%" }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 })
     .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
     .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/
The queue false should do the trick, take a look at the page and see it in action. You will need to scroll down a bit

Comment: luckily I just made a widget using this, yw

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, don't put the fade in the callback...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selector").click(function () {
        $(this).animate({left: "75px"}).fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $(this).addClass("selector-hover").fadeIn("fast");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kai. Unfortunately, it still triggers both effects separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is the effect of encasing the FadeIn inside the animate callback..
As the callback is fired after the end of the animation, so by the time the fade in starts the animation is already completed..

Try moving the fadeOut and fadeIn to outside the animate callback and it should be working fine..

Comment: Thanks for the answer sushanth. That's what I did after reading Kai's answer. Unfortunately, it still triggers both effects separately.